# Can I see the workings (console) of my bitcoin full node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, full-node

I have just completed the IBD of my bitcoin full node on Bitcoin Core on Linux. When I open Bitcoin Core, i just get the basic wallet interface. It there anyway of seeing what the node is doing behind the scenes through some sort of console and interface where I can search through the blockchain too?

If not, Is it possible on Ethereum clients?

Thank you

Comment: You mean something like `tail -f ~/.bitcoin/debug.log` (in a terminal)?

Answer (score 2):

You are running the Qt version of Bitcoin, which includes the GUI. If you have bitcoind, you can quit the Bitcoin application and type `bitcoind` into your terminal.

Otherwise, type `tail -f ~/.bitcoin/debug.log` in your terminal to see then end of the debug file, which will show you when new blocks arrive.

Alternatively, you can install bitcoind from Bitcoin.org. This is a different package than Bitcoin-Qt. Bitcoind only runs "in terminal" so there is no GUI.